# Update table from large select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table extradata that needs to be updated.  It needs to be updated for 863 different accounts.

Here is the query block that returns and puts into a temp table the account numbers that need to be changed.

Is there an easy way to do a bulk update from this query?

```
declare @tmp table (number int)

insert into @tmp
select accountid as number from letterrequest
where lettercode in ('97001','70003','19998','91009','20000','99100','19997','70002','99099','91008','97002','97210','97231')
and dateProcessed >= '2013-12-04'
union all
select number from gizmo_requests
where letterCode in (97001,70003,19998,91009,20000,99100,19997,70002,99099,91008,97002,97210,97231)
and dateProcessed >= '2013-12-04'
union all
select number from jm_efiling
where letter in (97001,70003,19998,91009,20000,99100,19997,70002,99099,91008,97002,97210,97231)
and datePrinted >= '2013-12-04'

select distinct * from @tmp
```

This query returns 863 rows of account ID's.

```
update extradata set line4 = 'TEST'
where extracode = 'L3'
and number in @tmp
```

only if the number column is in the temp table above.

Comment: Inner join of extracode to @tmp?

Comment: What do you mean by "easy"? Faster or just better code?

Comment: @shiva Easy as in an easy way to update 863 from a tmp table.  The only way I can think of doing it is a pain by setting up a while loop.

Comment: Oh Ok. Check out @YuriyGalanter's answer. That should do it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20555075/325521 You can also have UNIQUE Indexes on `TABLE` variables in case your `UPDATE` set is large. Check out DR Tom's Article on that. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175774(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
update extradata set line4 = 'TEST'
from extradata inner join @tmp T
on extradata.number = T.number
where extracode = 'L3'
```

You can use joins in update queries

Comment: Anyone to grab distinct values from @tmp?  For some reason when i inner join the two tables it returns 865 results.  but when i select distinct and inner join the two tables it returns 863.  Not sure why the non-distinct version returns two extra rows.

Comment: Perhaps you have some records with the same `number` in `extradata` table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` with a subquery in the `where` statement:

```
update extradata
    set line4 = 'TEST'
    where extracode = 'L3' and
          number in (select number from @tmp);
```